# How to reference a specific account in Solana programs with multiple accounts?

Tags: rust, anchor, solana

This program allows users to make an account to receive money.  So 'Alice' can create the account Fundraiser.  In Fundraiser, there is a specific variable amount_raised which keeps track of how much SOL has been sent to her account.  This program allows for multiple people to create new Fundraisers..SO, how do I reference the correct account in the function 'donate'?  I am suspecting that I need to use PDAs or at least iterate through all of the programs accounts and match it to the creator's pubkey.  Thank you in advance.  (Sol is sent in client, I just want to keep track of the amount_raised by adding the amount).

```
use super::*;

pub fn donate(ctx: Context<Donate>, amount: u32) -> ProgramResult {
    let fundraiser: &mut Account<Fundraiser> = &mut ctx.accounts.fundraiser;
    let user: &Signer = &ctx.accounts.user;
    fundraiser.amount_raised += amount;
    Ok(())
}


pub fn start_fund(ctx: Context<StartFund>, amount: u32, reason: String) -> ProgramResult {
    let fundraiser: &mut Account<Fundraiser> = &mut ctx.accounts.fundraiser;
    let author: &Signer = &ctx.accounts.author;
    let clock: Clock = Clock::get().unwrap();

    if reason.chars().count() > 350 {
        return Err(ErrorCode::ContentTooLong.into())
    }

    fundraiser.author = *author.key;
    fundraiser.amount_to_raise = amount;     
    fundraiser.timestamp = clock.unix_timestamp;
    fundraiser.reason = reason;
    Ok(())
}    

pub struct StartFund<'info> {
#[account(init, payer = author, space = 64 + 64)]
pub fundraiser: Account<'info, Fundraiser>,
#[account(mut)]
pub author: Signer<'info>,
#[account(address = system_program::ID)]
pub system_program: AccountInfo<'info>,
}    

#[derive(Accounts)]
pub struct Donate<'info> {
    #[account(mut)]
    pub fundraiser: Account<'info, Fundraiser>,
    #[account(mut)]
    pub user: Signer<'info>,
    #[account(address = system_program::ID)]
    pub system_program: AccountInfo<'info>,
    }        

#[account]
pub struct Fundraiser { 
 pub author: Pubkey,
 pub amount_to_raise: u32,
 pub amount_raised: u32,
 pub timestamp: i64,
 pub reason: String, //reason
}
```

}
`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've pretty much got it right -- in your `Donate` instruction, you'll also need to pass in Alice's `author` account, so that you can move transfer funds from `user` to `author` during `Donate`.  So instead, it'll look something like:

```
#[derive(Accounts)]
pub struct Donate<'info> {
    #[account(mut)]
    pub fundraiser: Account<'info, Fundraiser>,
    #[account(mut)]
    pub user: Signer<'info>,
    #[account(mut)]
    pub author: AccountInfo<'info>,
    #[account(address = system_program::ID)]
    pub system_program: AccountInfo<'info>,
}
```

And you'll have to check that the `author` provided matches `fundraiser.author`.

Comment: Hey, I thought I had it figured out but it keeps saying "key.toBuffer is not a function"... I am iterating through all of the accounts on client side and the account's pubkey.  Should I iterate on the solana program instead, in order to get the correct account to change 'amount_raised"?  I dont know why this part has to be so complicated.

Comment: I think I am getting what you mean in the derive(accounts) part, but I am very confused about how to go about this in the instruction area.  I cannot find anything about it online